# Difficulty understanding this error log

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

This is the crash that's coming after a `UITableViewCell` is clicked and is supposed to `segue` to another `UIViewController`. What's going wrong here ?

```
2014-04-25 09:41:58.388 Adune[36784:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ADNProfileViewController 0x111259fb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key job.'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024b0495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010220f99e objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102534919 -[NSException raise] + 9
        3   Foundation                          0x000000010037b530 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024ac400 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
        5   UIKit                               0x0000000100e738a6 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1131
        6   UIKit                               0x0000000100d0db0c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 245
        7   UIKit                               0x0000000100d0e149 -[UIViewController loadView] + 112
        8   UIKit                               0x0000000100d0e3b7 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
        9   UIKit                               0x0000000100d0e777 -[UIViewController view] + 29
        10  UIKit                               0x0000000100d252c5 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 628
        11  UIKit                               0x0000000100d306f5 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 401
        12  UIKit                               0x0000000100d31238 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
        13  UIKit                               0x0000000100e4b895 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
        14  UIKit                               0x0000000100c78993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
        15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100981802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
        16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100976369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
        17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001009761ea _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
        18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001008e9fb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
        19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001008eb030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
        20  QuartzCore                          0x00000001008eb69d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010247bdc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010247bd37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010245b522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010245ad83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        25  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001041e8f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
        26  UIKit                               0x0000000100c18e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
        27  Adune                               0x0000000100013a03 main + 115
        28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102b485fd start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Comment: Please search on the error. This issue has been discussed many times before. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key

Comment: I looked. Tried many solutions. There's some specific error I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in making the necessary connections. 2 objects were pointing to the same outlet.